# Xcode, how many of memory allocations were freed?(Alternative of Valgrind)

Tags: c, xcode, malloc, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am using Xcode for debugging of my C program, and I want to make sure that all memory allocations has been freed when the program is finished. However, I am not sure how can I see if there is any alloc that is left not freed.

I know that it is possible to do using Valgrind on machines running on Linux. Would appreciate if someone suggests alternative for Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 and it would be even better if there is a way of doing it on Xcode.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the program is finished"? When it terminates? In that case it is irrelevant, the OS will reclaim all allocated memory, released or not by the program.

Comment: Simply, I want to see how many of memory allocations have been freed.

Comment: You are right that memory used by program is reclaimed by OS once the program is terminated. However, I still believe that freeing memory is a good practice of checking if the program is in consistent state when it is freed.

Answer (score 0):

When I am looking at memory accumulation (not being released) I use the Xcode profiler and Heap Shot, see For HowTo use Heap Shot (now named Mark Generation) to find memory creap: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/).

Also see the memory diagnostics under "Edit Scheme""Diagnostics": Enable Scribble, Enable Guard Edges, Enable Guard Malloc and Malloc Stack.

Answer (score 0):

valgrind is available on MacOS.
See valgrind web site:
"X86/Darwin and AMD64/Darwin (Mac OS X 10.9, with limited support for 10.8)."

So, that looks a good alternative to valgrind on linux, if you
want to use MacOS.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that; but this version is not supported on Yosemite(10.10.1)